# In what sense is economic growth cumulative?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, economic-growth

In my economics syllabus, one of the student competences is to "Show the cumulative nature of growth and measure average and annual rates of growth". What I don't understand is how a country's GDP growth can be subject to cumulative or compounding effects?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is simple. If you grow 1% each year for five years you end up with a GDP that is (1.01)^5 of what you started: the 1% growth of each year accumulates over time.